# Is it common to have dependency between facade layer?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

My application have the follow layer:
- Facade
- Business Object
- Repository (Spring JPA Data)

Let's suppose the follow classes:

```
@Component
public class MessageFacade implements MessageService {
  @Autowired
  private GarageBO garageBO;
  @Autowired
  private MessageBO messageBO;

  public void createFeedbackMessage(...) {
    messageBO.createFeedbackMessage(...);
    garageBO.createFeedback(...);
  }
}

@Component
public class ServiceOrderFacade implements ServiceOrderService {     
  @Autowired
  private ServiceOrderBO serviceOrderBO;
  @Autowired
  private MessageBO messageBO;
  @Autowired
  private GarageBO garageBO;

  public void createServiceOrder(...) {
    serviceOrderBO.createServiceOrder(...);
    messageBO.createFeedbackMessage(...);
    garageBO.createFeedback(...);
  }
}
```

Observing the createFeedbackMessage method in MessageFacade i have:
**1)** The createFeedbackMessage method in MessageBO it's responsible to create an email with the feedback survey **LINK**;
**2)** The createFeedbackMessage method in garageBO creates the Feedback **ENTITY** with the questions and responses;

On createServiceOrder method in ServiceOrderFacade i need to call an method of ServiceOrderBO and after i need to have the same behavior of createFeedbackMessage method in MessageFacade.

Is it a bad idea to create a dependency between ServiceOrderFacade -> MessageFacade ?

The code would be:

```
@Component
public class ServiceOrderFacade implements ServiceOrderService {     
  @Autowired
  private ServiceOrderBO serviceOrderBO;
  @Autowired
  private MessageBO messageBO;
  @Autowired
  private GarageBO garageBO;

  public void createServiceOrder(...) {
    serviceOrderBO.createServiceOrder(...);
    getMessageService().createFeedbackMessage(...);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you think in [DRY(don't repeat yourself)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) you have an problem. You can create another layer like a common that is dependency of Business Object layer and will be created once and will be used in your entire BO if U want

Comment: There is a name for this another layer ?
I solved on the way detailed above, but is very ugly since in future can i have an circular dependency.
I will follow your suggestion, thanks for the response!

Comment: Here we call it's by common layer. In this layer you can concentrate your Repository, BO even Facade layer. I did not understand when U'll have circular dependency ? In my opnion this layer always will be a module that never will depend of for example an Facade

Comment: Sorry, i expressed myself wrong. I meant to say that i solved as i suggested in my own question using: getMessageService().createFeedbackMessage(...);
Solving this way can create an circular dependency.